# How to update and increment a database?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have code for a delete function which works. The columns in the db are COL_TASK_TITLE and COL_NUM . my increment function isn't working. I have also provided the delete function below which fully works.

```
   public void deleteTask(View view) {

        View parent = (View) view.getParent();
        TextView taskTextView = (TextView) 
        parent.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
        String task = String.valueOf(taskTextView.getText());
        SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
        TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + " = ?",
        new String[]{task});
        db.close();
        updateUI();
    }


    public void incrment(View view) {
        View parent = (View) view.getParent();
        TextView taskTextView = (TextView) 
        parent.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
        String task = String.valueOf(taskTextView.getText());
        SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("COL_NUM",COL_NUM+1)
        db.update(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,cv
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + " = ?",
            new String[]{task});
        db.close();
        updateUI();
    }
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `increment()`? I highly suspect you don't actually need it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `COL_NUM` is the name of the column, right? 
So this line is wrong:

```
cv.put("COL_NUM", COL_NUM + 1);
```

because you think that you add a number to the value of the column where in reality you concatenate `1` to the name of the column. 
What you must do is increment the current value by 1 like this:

```
db.execSQL(
    "update " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE + 
    " set " + COL_TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_NUM + " = " + COL_TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_NUM + " + 1" + 
    " where " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + " = ?", new Object[] {task});
```

If there is a case that `COL_NUM` is `null` then change the statement to this:

```
db.execSQL(
    "update " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE + 
    " set " + COL_TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_NUM + " = coalesce(" + COL_TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_NUM + ", 0) + 1" + 
    " where " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + " = ?", new Object[] {task});
```

So change your method to this:

```
public void incrment(View view) {
    View parent = (View) view.getParent();
    TextView taskTextView = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
    String task = taskTextView.getText().toString();
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL(
        "update " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE +
        " set " + COL_TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_NUM + " = coalesce(" + COL_TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_NUM + ", 0) + 1" +
        " where " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + " = ?", new Object[] {task}
    );
    db.close();
    updateUI();
}
```

Of course you could use the `update()` method like you do, but first you should find the existing value in `COL_NUM`, increment it, put it in `cv` and then execute `update()`.

Comment: `new Object() {task}` not work object[]  (String,byte[],Long,Double) only work. `new Object[]{task}`  other `new String[]{task}` you must use. You read doco must.

Comment: @Halcn of course it works: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#execSQL(java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.Object%5B%5D)

Comment: error gives unknown class. doco say *Object[] bindArgs* so need object array (object[]) not object. find out you test answer you say.

Comment: @Halcn right. Instead of square brackets I put parentheses. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the update method the value in the 2nd parameter of the ContentValues put (i.e. COL_NUM+1) is treated as a string and enclosed in single quotes so the resultant value becomes the string **`COL_NUM1`** which ends up being the value stored in the column specified by the 1st parameter.

- *The enclosing of values is intended, at least in part, to offer protection against SQL Injection. However, in such cases, it is a bit of a hindrance.*

In such a case then you can execute SQL directly via the **execSQL** method. To protect against SQL injection you can use the **execSQL** that takes two paramters. The second parameter being arguments that will replace ? placeholders. [execSQL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#execSQL(java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.Object%5B%5D)).

- Where it says *Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.* Is not actually the case. Rather it is (should be) a warning as per (from the execSQL that takes no 2nd parameter)
- > It has no means to return any data (such as the number of affected
  >   rows). Instead, you're encouraged to use insert(java.lang.String,
  >   java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues),
  >   update(java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues,
  >   java.lang.String, java.lang.String[]), et al, when possible.

That is run the SQL **`UPDATE the_table SET COL_NUM = COL_NUM + 1 WHERE COL_TASK_TITLE = the_title`**

- (where the_table and the_title are changed accordingly).
- *the update method generates and executes the SQL `UPDATE the_table SET COL_NUM = 'COL_NUM1' WHERE COL_TASK_TITLE = 'the_title'`. Hence the issue.*

You could use the following method :-

```
public void incrment(View view) {
    View parent = (View) view.getParent();
    TextView taskTextView = (TextView) 
    parent.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
    String task = String.valueOf(taskTextView.getText());        
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    db.execSQL(
            "UPDATE " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE +
            " SET " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_NUM + " = " + 
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_NUM + "+ 1 " +
            " WHERE " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + " = ?",
            new String[]{task}
    );

    /*
    // Alternative with COL_NUM hard coded rather than retrieved via TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_NUM
    db.execSQL("UPDATE " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE +
            " SET COL_NUM  = COL_NUM + 1 " +
            "WHERE " +TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + " = ?"
            ,new String[]{task}
            );
    */
    db.close();
    updateUI();
}
```

- This assumes that TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_NUM is defined (using a single source for the names reduces the chance for errors, if not then you use the commented out alternative that uses the hard coded COL_NUM (removing or commenting out the db.execSQL currently used)